# How to Cache notification data obtain by Ajax call?

Tags: java, javascript, html, session

I am using push notification services in my web application,one of my project requirement is to cache notification data obtain by Ajax call so that same data can be viewed when user switch from one page to another page,

I have 3 flow To implement Above cases scenario

> flow:1
>
> Cache notification data in javascript object and while redirecting page
>   serialize obj using $.param() , send data in browser url (in such case my data
>   will be visible).
>
> flow:2
>
> Cache data in browser local storage or session storage to send data
>   from one page to another page again here for different browser local
>   storage or session storage will be varied as mention on [this link](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/)
>
> flow:3
>
> As i am using java as server side language i can send notification obj
>   in request to server ,can use servlet session to store notification
>   ,while switching from one page to another load a servlet which send me
>   notification detail object in response while page is still loading this is not >considering as caching as i have to load and store notification data each time when new >page gets load.

Here what is preferable solution?? ,from flow 1 and 2 ofcause there is `security issues` while flow 3 is more secure but it will effect on my bandwidth data limit.

Edit(my reasons having security issues with flow 1 and flow 2)

folw-1:
       Passing data using query string us such a easy task to implement ,but every data which is passed between pages(in form of query string) is visible in url which is against our project needs

flow-2
      for flow-2 with referance to this link description given by Nicholas C. Zakas security issues with session storage is as below

> "You log into a web site to view your mail and the mail application saves information 
>   about those emails in sessionStorage.
>   Then, you switch tabs to another window where you log out of the
>   account from which your email is being read. This is very possible
>   when using single sign-on IDs such as a Yahoo! ID (but please note
>   this is just an example, Yahoo! doesn’t actually do this). You then
>   switch back to the email tab and your data is still present in
>   sessionStorage even though you’ve logged out. Clicking on various
>   email messages retrieves data from sessionStorage and displays it.
>   You’re now looking at personal information while logged out."

my question is as below

> How to Cache notification data obtain by Ajax call?are there
>   any other way beside above flow!!!

thanks in advance

Comment: You have to explain in what way flow 1 and 2 are security issues (as in: from your perspective). Nothing is black & white; leaving the door of your house open is a security issue if you go do shopping, but it is not a problem if you're standing right in front of it so to say. I'm upvoting the question anyway as this has the potential to become a very relevant question in this day and age if you improve it to be less opinionated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow 2, but using local storage.
  Not limited to the window, by using the broadcast event as shown here: http://bens.me.uk/2013/localstorage-inter-window-messaging (open the demo twice to see it in action)

JS code here:
http://blog.fastmail.fm/2012/11/26/inter-tab-communication-using-local-storage/

On logout event you can clear local storage through the exact same inter window messaging, so storage.clear() cleared everywhere. I.e OnClick -> storage.clear() -> POST/GO TO logout request

Then you can set on the server a variable in a database for if they are signed in or not, if they are send the data straight away, else redirect to login page (for notification reloads from different widows where the logout might not have affected the current view yet, so view on change check quickly, simple check with next to no bandwidth use, maybe a few byte if correctly done).

Also can add a check if its the last window, then on unload clear local storage.

As for the data being stored in clear view strings, use an encryption algorithm before storing, i.e. change all binary data by some calculation on a random number, then store the binary representation in plain view.
Not the most secure but a human couldn't understand it. 
Plus at the end of the day if someones wanting to steal your data from local storage then the user needs to be logged in and the 'hacker' needs to have a JS file knowing exactly what it's looking for, so extremely targeted.

So change it up by making the int to change by something like userid * random int used / last names binary representation. So it's completely different and hence has to be know every part of the key calculation.

Comment: thank you vary much for your answer,really helpful stuff,can you give me any example of encryption algorithm which i can use for changing all binary data by some calculation on a random number!

Comment: Look here:    http://www.midnight-coding.com/2014/05/convert-string-to-binary-to-string.html    Then you can get a random number by using javascripts Math.Random(), store this as an open key, but maybe have that key pre-suffixed by the usersID    I.e 123442454-2948 where 2948 is another random number we create and store openly.    Then the one actually used to get the random number used to change the binary is stored openly as it has to be appended to the users id to actually get the key to decode back to binary before the string conversion takes place again.

Comment: I.e Open string, append : 2948 -> {{UserID}}-2948 : 209375 -> First Name : ((Str to Binary * 209375)) etc.. then decrypt work backwards.

Comment: thanks for above link,here  you are suggesting to generate a random number for each user ,store it in databases and every time i want to access local storage[for retrieving notification msg back] appending random number with the open key , in this case if some one figure out what is random number for one user ,he/she can easily decrypt binary to string,my question is how to make this process more secure ,if i generate new random number [as a key] on server will it be more secure??

Comment: Yes possibly, so if you know your random key on the server you could send encrypted data then decrypt on user side with public key. So maybe make the passwords binary form the public key and use a RSA type encryption method.  So from the passwords binary form, or somehow numerical form, work backwards to get the private key for which you use in the server to transmit encrypted data.  But still you'll have to then store the passwords numerical form in a browser session. But most secure you can get without affecting the user experience, ie password every time they want to see data.